# Is it possible to trigger a real click to prevent execute PopUp Blocker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, click

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" onClick="performSyncronousRequest();">

<script>
function performSyncronousRequest() {
    $.ajax({

     data: {},
     success: function(){
         window.open(\'http://www.google.com\');
     },
     async: false
    });
}
</script>
```

if i execute the click live in BRowser it opens a new tab in browser without a Popup Warning

but if i execute it with

```
$(#myButton).click();
```

then the popblocker is activated

is there a possibility to avoid this

Comment: No more possible on modern browser. On older one, dispatching event would have work IIRC

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#myButton').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Don't exactly know, but I remember using this instead of click() to solve the same error, but probably I'm wrong then.

Comment: Maybe you were thinking about that instead: `$('#myButton')[0].click();`

Comment: Yes that's possible, but indeed it seems to be abolished in modern browsers.